# android tab layout text is hiding when text style is set to italic

Tags: java, android

[image: In image the information text is not displaying properly.At the end of the word N is hiding]

//Here is the xml code

```
 <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/inforStatusTab"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                app:tabIndicator="@drawable/btn_corner3"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/materialBlue"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/materialBlue"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/tab_text"
                app:tabTextColor="@android:color/black">


                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/information"
                    />

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/approval"
                    />
            </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

//Here is the style for tab layout

```
<style name="tab_text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/poppins_bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_10sdp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    </style>
```

I am implementing tab layout in my app the issue is when i try to set italic for tab text the text is not displaying properly.

Comment: try using the AppCompatTextView

Comment: i changed the textview into AppCompatTextView no changes the issue remains same

Comment: are you using a material theme for the app?

Comment: no i am not using

Comment: try a material theme in your styles.xml

Comment: material theme is also not working for italic fontstyle

Comment: You're using a bold font that probably doesn't hold the information on how to display italics. Either add the italics equivalent to your project or use a font that supports italics as well.

Comment: yeah try a different font

Comment: thank you for your suggestion i tried with different font now it is working